# Calling a function in the second loop returns unexpected value

Tags: python, cmdb, netbox

I'm mapping my switches to a tool called Netbox which is a CMDB tool.

I have a list of switches for example: `[US-switch01, US-switch02]`
If those devices don't exist in Netbox, I would like to create that device. Here is the script right now:

```py
import pynetbox
nb = pynetbox.api(
    'http://netbox.domain.com',
    token='token'
)

devices = nb.dcim.devices.all() # An object of all devices in my Netbox instance
sites = nb.dcim.sites.all() # An object of all sites in my Netbox instance (EU, US for example)

def getSiteID(site):
    for s in sites:
        if s.name.upper() == site.upper():
            return s.id # Returns the ID of the site given to is. For example US site ID is 1. EU site ID is 2.

def getDeviceID(device):
    for d in devices:
        if d.name.upper() == device.upper():
            return d.id

if __name__ == "__main__":
    switch_list = ["US-switch01", "US-switch02"]
    for switch in switch_list:
        print(f"Working on {switch}")
        if getDeviceID(switch) is None:
            siteName = switch.split('-')[0]
            print(siteName, getSiteID(siteName))
```

When I run my script, I first test what it would find:

```py
print(siteName, getSite(siteName))
```

So the above print should return `siteName` and the Side ID, which is what `getSite()` is doing.
The expected output is:

```
Working on US-switch01
US 1 #site name is US and the ID in netbox is 1
Working on US-switch02
EU 2 #site name is US and the ID in netbox is 1
```

For some reason, the output is this:

```
Working on US-switch01
US 1
Working on US-switch02
US None
```

Why do I get `None` as the returned value on the 2nd loop?

### The weird part

If I use this list: `[US-switch01, EU-switch01]` then the script works:

```
Working on US-switch01
US 1
Working on EU-switch02
EU 2
```

So the issue seems to be when there are 2 consecutive switches with the same site. Why? What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `devices` and `sites` objects?

Comment: It's a `pynetbox` object, so can't print it directly but looping over it shows the entire list of sites and devices I have. I can do a simple `for device in devices` and print `device.name` for example. If that what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you get generators (not lists) from the method `.all()`. So in the second call the generator has remembered the position from the first call. Try to make lists of the results of `.all()`.

```
devices = list(nb.dcim.devices.all())
sites = list(nb.dcim.sites.all())
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Wow, you saved me so much headache. I was about to add exceptions to each function to call that `.all()` method if it returned None. It works perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: Also: https://github.com/netbox-community/pynetbox/pull/476/files